# Mapbox Map Styles Pixelated

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm using mapbox map-gl-js as the mapping solution for one of my projects and right now using a custom map style designed in mapbox studio. When I zoom in up to some level, the map's road layers becomes pixalated like in the attached photo. Sometimes, rarely it works fine, but most of the time it's like this. Earlier I've using default map styles by mapbox itself, and the problem was there - so can't be an issue with the custom map style. Anyone has any solution for this?

P.S. - I'm actually using [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) as the mapbox wrapper for react.

[image: Pixalated Map]

Comment: Consider adding a [codepen](https://codepen.io) with working code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you share your style.json file?

Comment: @chriswhong yeah sure. Will add a one.

Comment: @StephenTaylor what did you mean by style.json? The mapbox json file? I'm actually using mapbox studio generated style.

Comment: You need to provide a hosted version of your site for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't "pixellated". It looks like the style has been modified to make those lines much thicker (`line-width`) than you expect. Note the labels are still the right size.

Comment: Hmm no, the design is all fine. Sometimes this works fine, sometimes not. If it's an issue on the design, then it should be always like that IMO